In a vision transformer, are the patch outputs for the last layer unused?
In a vision transformer (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.11929 ), it seems like the final MLP head for prediction is attached only to the last layer's [cls] token embedding (Figure 1 and Eqn 4).
Does this mean that:

other tokens' (i.e. image patches') final layer outputs are unused?
final transformer block gets trained only on the [cls] token?
as a consequence of (2), final layer outputs for other tokens will not have meaningful outputs, and another application should not use those outputs?
for efficiency, final transformer block can be run only for the [cls] token, ignoring other tokens?

